# ItemAdded is not firing for listitem

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

I like to set permission for listitem customlly.But ItemAdded is not firied for listitem.
Plz help me

Comment: Please elaborate your question, might be can help you better.

Comment: Thanx for ur reply...Event handler is not fired for Item Added.

Comment: Plz help me....

Answer (score 1):

First of all please Download [Sharepoint Manger](http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/22762) and check if event receiver attached to list or not.

if it is attached properly, in few rare instances where the event handler is not firing.

Does it related to SharePoint timer services or something else?

here is the way you can add event receiver through code.

```
private void AddEventReceiverToList(string siteUrl, string listName, string className,    string AssemblyFullName)   
{   
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())   
{   
    try  
    {   
        SPList list = web.Lists[listName];   
        if (list != null)   
        {   
            int receivers = list.EventReceivers.Count;    
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;   
            bool isAddedReceiverExist = false;   
            for (int i = 0; i < receivers; i++)   
            {   
                SPEventReceiverDefinition eventReceiver = list.EventReceivers[i];   
                if (eventReceiver.Class == className &&  eventReceiver.Type == SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded)   
                {   
                    isAddedReceiverExist = true;   
                    break;   
                }   
            }   
            if (!isAddedReceiverExist)   
                  list.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded, AssemblyFullName, className);   
        }   
    }   
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        //magic here
    } 
    finally  
    {   
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;   
    }   
}   

}  



AddEventReceiverToList("http://spsite-test:231/TestOMatic", "EventReceiverClassName",  "EventReceiverAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a865f0ecc234ea51");
```

Comment: i download Sharepoint Manager.how to check event receiver is attached to list or not using SharePoint Manager

Comment: you can run SharePoint Manager on your SharePoint server (make sure you do a 'run as administrator' for the first time), then just navigate to your appropriate list, and open up event receivers. It will display everything attached.

Comment: ya i checked by Sharepoint manager....but nothing in the EventReceivers.Wht i have to do now???

Comment: That means your event is not attached to the specific list. you can add eventreceiver by code to, i have edited my answer with code, please refer that

Comment: i m creating custom list in the name Sample.And i created the Event Receiver for Item Added.Then what i have to do???

Comment: I think then you have not registered your event, please http://claytonj.wordpress.com/2008/04/02/registering-sharepoint-event-handlers/ refer this url.

Comment: thank u so much...i ll try nd let u know soon

Comment: does your problem solved?